# ggplot: How to change labels to percentages on the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentage

This is the head of my data set:

```
structure(list(Aasta = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), 
tvs = c("Püsiv töövõimetus", "Püsiv töövõimetus", 
"Püsiv töövõimetus", "Püsiv töövõimetus", "Püsiv töövõimetus", 
"Püsiv töövõimetus"), Protsent = c(0.001, 0.018, 0.014, 
0.012, 0.013, 0.017)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is my plot:

```
ggplot(merilen2, aes(y = Protsent, x = Aasta, color = tvs, label = Protsent))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(label.size = 0, 
                            label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
                            size = 3, 
                            min.segment.length = 0.2, 
                            vjust=-0.5,
                            show.legend = F)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = merilen2$Aasta, labels = merilen2$Aasta)+
  scale_color_manual(values = cen_cols)+
  labs(x = 'Aasta',
       y = 'Protsent',
       color = 'Töövõime staatus')+
  cen_theme()
```

This is the outcome right now:

[image]

I need the labels as percentages (with one decimal place) on the graph, but don't know who to do that.

Comment: You can use the `scales::pecent` function for easy formatting. Inside your aes use `label = scales::percent(Protsent, scale=1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `label` in `aes` to -

```
label = paste0(round(Protsent * 100, 1), '%')
```

Complete code -

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(merilen2, aes(y = Protsent, x = Aasta, color = tvs, 
                     label = paste0(round(Protsent * 100, 1), '%')))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(label.size = 0, 
                            label.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"), 
                            size = 3, 
                            min.segment.length = 0.2, 
                            vjust=-0.5,
                            show.legend = F)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = merilen2$Aasta, labels = merilen2$Aasta)+
  labs(x = 'Aasta',
       y = 'Protsent',
       color = 'Töövõime staatus')
```

Removed `scale_color_manual` because  `cen_cols` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
  scale_y_continuous(label=scales::label_percent(.1)) +
```